# How to collapse string variables such that they appear concatenated?

Tags: stata

I have a dataset that looks like :

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRAOJ.jpg)

I want to collapse the data in Stata such that the data appears as :

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CWaq.jpg)

I am aware that if Product were a numeric variable we could use the collapse command. However, I don't know what to do in this situation since Product is a string variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lacking a reproducible example, I'll supply an untested answer. Something like the following might set you in the right direction.

```
bysort year type (product): generate str1000 products = trim(product[1])
bysort year type (product): replace products = product[_n-1]+","+trim(product) if _n>1
bysort year type (product): generate totsales = sum(sales)
bysort year type (product): keep if _n==_N
drop product sales
```